# Right way to save has_many item before save on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, many-to-many

I'm developing a Rails application. My application is like a equipaments location system, so, a I have items with name, price, id, etc. This items is the model called Equipament, which belongs to a model called Event, which has attributes date, total price, etc.

To use a equipament model more than once, I created a relation model called equipament_event to perfom a many to many relation, just like a shopping cart, where I can add items to my cart and when I confirm, save the order with the items through the secondary table who have the id`s of order and product.

I thought I'd use in form event a combination of jquery and ajax to perform add and delete equipament_item where I can add or remove equipament from event. But, to create an equipament_event, firstly, I need the id of event that this to be created, but, how can I get the id to add equipament_event if the event is still not saved in database?? I need to use jquery and ajax for a dinamic calculate of price.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I would persist this information to the database, but use another mechanism (like a status field) to indicate that the event hadn't been finalized yet.  This allows you to use all of the things that Rails does well instead of figuring out how to jam this all into a cookie, or any data source that's not persisted.

This is not the only approach, but it's what I would do.

Comment: Thanks for response, Jim :) I understand what you explain, but i trying to use a solution to create items with the id of equipament selected in Jquery append list and the event what to be created afte confirm button. I think to create the items only the event model is save, but i need to pass JQuery elements to controller, but i know its imposible :/